# CSS Newbie: Position a Div over Each of a Row of Photos

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm new to CSS and racking my brain on the following:

I have a row of images that are sourced from a database query.  I display the photos in a row which wraps within a page.  For example, if there are 20 photos, it will display 5 per row based on the width of the page and the photo.

My challenge: I want to position a DIV in the same relative spot on each photo.  This div will contain a link to take an action on the photo.  All of the action code is working, but I cannot, for the life of me, correctly position the DIV.

I can't post an image of the mockup I'm trying to achieve (I'm too new), but here's a description:

Imagine a row of photos the size of a postage stamp.  In the upper right corner of each, is a gray box containing a link.  I'm unable to consistently position the gray box in the same relative position on each photo. Each photo is the same size, but since the number of photos is unknown, I can't simply "position:abosulte;" the action box manually.

My HTML looks roughly as follows: I've simplified the loop; its a dump of a query from ColdFusion of an indeterminate number of photos.

```
<LOOP>

    <div id="photo" style="display:inline;"><img src="abc"></div>
    <div id="redBox" style="????"><a href="javascript:action(photo);">ACTION</a></div>

</LOOP>
```

Thoughts?

Many kind thanks in advance.

Comment: btw: an id must be unique within a document, so you can't use it in a loop

Comment: +1 for @harpax use a `class` attribute for both "photo" and "redBox"

Comment: @harpax, you're correct; the actual DIV ID is relative to the query row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could wrap it all in another div?

```
<LOOP>
    <div class="container" style="display: inline-block;">
        <div class="photo"><img src="abc"></div>
        <div class="redBox" style="position:relative; top: -20px; right; 10px;"><a href="javascript:action(photo);">ACTION</a></div>
    </div>
</LOOP>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<style>
#photo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.action {
    /* Optional */
    background: #CCC;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    /* Necessary */
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
```

<div id="photo">
    <div class="action">Foo</div>
    <img src="abc">
</div>

Comment: Close, but the #photo `div` must also be `inline-block`, otherwise it won't have the dimensions of the img contained inside.

Comment: Ah. Learned something new! :)   Thanks.  Shame you can't upvote comments.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier to add your box within this div, something like:

```
<div id="photo" style="display:inline;">
<div id="redBox" style="position:relative;top:-10px;left:-10px"><a    href="javascript:action(photo);">ACTION</a></div>
<img src="abc">
</div>
```

You could then offset as required using position:relative (you'll see I've guessed the amounts above, but you can obviously tweak to suit!)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note - simshaun's response below is better code, was deliberately trying to keep your code as similar as possible so you'd understand, but would definitely try and understand his if you can too!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel...

Check out the [`map`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp) element ([HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.6), [HTML 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-map-element.html#image-maps))